# How to use Open Weather API Icons

Tags: javascript

I want use "[Open Weather ICON](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons)" to show weather condition in my app. But
cant find any more information to how display icon from fetch code like 09d or id like 300.

```html
{
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":300,
         "main":"Drizzle",
         "description":"light intensity drizzle",
         "icon":"09d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations"
}
```

[SOLVED]
its my fault. i use same NPM Module and fogget to link OWI css. now it work!

Comment: the page you linked to explains exactly how to use them! https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons#basic-usage

Comment: ADyson, I was reading that, but it assumes you have the class name. How do you get the class name from the 09d value?

Comment: See https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ - it compares the IDs to the class names. I think maybe you can use either one in your element, or you'll have to create a mapping table. Or of course you can look at the source code and find out: https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons/blob/master/css/weather-icons.css

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at this page from their documentation
https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html

seems like when you would write your tag
`<i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>`
you might right it like

`<i class="wi wi-owm-[id]"></i>`
if you use the id 300 you would end up with
`<i class="wi wi-owm-300"></i>` which is the sprinkle icon

hope that might help get you on the right track

Comment: how does this relate to the codes like "09d" given in the example? There's no mapping, on that page you linked to, between the two things. https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ does contain the type of codes given in the question, and shows the classes they map to

Comment: As I understand it's not related with `09d`, but with the id, see [the provided link](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html) and look for "Open Weather Map", then you'll see the mappings from id to class name, like this one: `wi-owm-300: sprinkle `

Comment: it not work! when i use <i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i> it will be ok. but <i class="wi wi-owm-300"></i> not show anything

Comment: @user3188348 , silly question but can you confirm all the files you need are in your project and referenced correctly. In the documentation it says 
"Place the 5 font files and the main weather-icons.min.css file in your project, with the assumption that the fonts are located up ../ from your CSS directory."

There might be a file that references ID classes that is missing. Thats the only thing i can think of.

Comment: @p4ttch, i did that, "<i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>" WORK. <<<<< but when i use id it not work!